# Scraping literal class description in Python 3 using lxml xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I have a small question regarding my webscraper. 
I am trying to scrape the rating per review of a website on trustpilot. 
Let's take for instance https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.amazon.com 
Even though i managed to scrape the review content and title, i can't seem to get a hold of the amount of stars given (1 to 5).

If i look at the html code, it doesn't show 'text' so i can assign the specific class to it (like i did with content and title).

However, the amount of stars given is mentioned in the class description itself - a 5-star ratings has the element : `div class=''star-rating count-5 size-medium clearfix''. a 2-star rating the following: iv class=''star-rating count-2 size-medium clearfix''`

This class is located within: div class="review-info clearfix"

Does anybody know how I can scrape the literal class, or only the count-x element per review?

Answer (score 0):

The class can be easily extracted using BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
c = requests.get('https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.amazon.com').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
reviews = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'review-stack'})
for review in reviews[:5]:
    print(review.find('div', {'class': 'star-rating'})['class'])
```

This prints out the following lists:

```
['star-rating', 'count-5', 'size-medium', 'clearfix']
['star-rating', 'count-5', 'size-medium', 'clearfix']
['star-rating', 'count-1', 'size-medium', 'clearfix']
['star-rating', 'count-4', 'size-medium', 'clearfix']
['star-rating', 'count-4', 'size-medium', 'clearfix']
```

Now you just need to select the right element of the list and you have your rating.

Using lxml:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.amazon.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

reviews = tree.xpath("//div[@class='review-info clearfix']/div[1]")
for rev in reviews:
    print(rev.get('class'))
```

Comment: Hi druidmaciek thank you for your quick reply! I want to make a list of all the 20 reviews of that specific page, so review 1 gives a rating of 5 stars, the second 3 etc. Do you think there is a way of doing this via lxml (as the rest of my code also is made of lxml and xpath codes).

Comment: @TZnl, Where is your code and what have you tried so far with the way you expect to move on?

Comment: @SIM see my answer. it is too long to add as a comment

Comment: Who has suggested you to paste that as a comment? You could have edited your question with that failure attempt?

Comment: i think the solution by @druidmaciek worked. Great thanks!!

Comment: Sorry @SIM i am fairly new to stackoverflow so i still have to find out how things work. Sorry for the inconvenience ;)